# Prove all reversible heat engines that work between just two temperatures have the same efficiency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, heat-engine

Can someone explain this explanation to me:

> A completely different argument focuses on the requirement that the
>   device only move heat at one or other of the two temperatures. Then,
>   provided we have previously independently developed the concept of
>   entropy, for all systems, we almost immediately (reversible entails no
>   net entropy change) have the Qs being in the same ratio as the Ts,
>   whence the familiar formula for efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the system - engine plus sources - is isolated and reversible, we have $\Delta S = 0$. The entropy change of the system after a complete cycle of the engine is just
$$\Delta S=\Delta S_{\mathrm{sources}},$$
since $\Delta S_{\mathrm{engine}}=0$ for a cycle. Consider the hot reservoir at temperature $T_1$. To calculate its change of entropy we imagine a reversible process where the source transfer heat $|Q_1|$ at constant temperature $T_1$. Hence,
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{source1}}=-\frac{|Q_1|}{T_1}.$$
For the cold reservoir at temperature $T_2$ we got
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{source2}}=+\frac{|Q_2|}{T_2}.$$
Therefore
$$\Delta S=-\frac{|Q_1|}{T_1}+\frac{|Q_2|}{T_2}=0,$$
i.e.
$$\frac{|Q_2|}{|Q_1|}=\frac{T_2}{T_1}.$$

On the other hand, the efficiency of a thermal engine is
$$\eta=\frac{W}{|Q_1|}=1-\frac{|Q_2|}{|Q_1|},$$
so any reversible engine has
$$\eta=1-\frac{T_2}{T_1}.$$